# Kentico - Display List of related articles based on categories/subcategories

Tags: kentico

I have many articles and each is assigned under different categories/subcategories.
What I'd like to do is at the end of individual article, I'll display a list of Related Articles based on the category(s) that the current article is placed. I've added a Repeater but don't really know what to put in Content Filter/Category Name to achieve this. Hope it's not so complex. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in Portal without touching the code if you need to.  The following steps are how you can achieve it (though they are rough and ready!)

1. In your **Article** page type, create a new query.  This queries job is going to be to link the existing *Document* to any others that share the exact same categories.  Your query should look like this:

```
    SELECT ##TOPN## ##COLUMNS##
    FROM View_CMS_Tree_Joined rel
    INNER JOIN CMS_DocumentCategory relcat ON relcat.DocumentID=rel.DocumentID
    INNER JOIN CMS_DocumentCategory doccat ON relcat.CategoryID=doccat.CategoryID
    WHERE ##WHERE##
    AND rel.DocumentID  doccat.DocumentID
    ORDER BY ##ORDERBY##
```

2. Now, replace you **Repeater** with a **Repeater with custom query**. In the setting, choose your newly created query for the **Query name** field using the selector control.
3. Set the **WHERE clause** to be `doccat.DocumentID={% CurrentDocument.DocumentID #%}`
4. Pick the appropriate transformation and you *should* be good to go.

This method requires an exact category match, so *Categories > Cars > Mazda* will not match to *Categories > Cars*.

Hopefully this is of some use :)

Comment: This did help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.kenticosolutions.com/Developer-Tips/Tip/September-2013/Creating-a-Document-Category-Filter.aspx) may give you some idea on creating a filter, but I don't think this is exactly what you want. It does show you have to get the documents thru the API.

You could do a custom query, something like this

```
    SELECT *
FROM dbo.View_CMS_Tree_Joined vctj
WHERE vctj.DocumentID IN
(
    SELECT DocumentID
    FROM CMS_DocumentCategory
    WHERE CategoryID IN
    (
        SELECT CategoryID
        FROM CMS_Category
        WHERE dbo.CMS_Category.CategoryName = 'Name Here'
    )
);
```